# The calculation behind progress circle using dasharray and dashoffset

Tags: css, angularjs, svg

I'm building a small angularjs directive which will display a progress circle(I don't want animation) and there will be a text in the middle of it indicating the percentage of completion.
The html code of the circle is:

```
   <path fill="none" stroke="rgb(0,51,117)" stroke-width="5" stroke-linecap="square" d="M25,2.5A22.5,22.5 0 1 1 2.5,25A22.5,22.5 0 0 1 25,2.5" stroke-dasharray="105" stroke-dashoffset="{{circle.percentage*(-140)/100 + 105 }}">
    </path>
```

I don't know the calculation behind the dasharray and dashoffset, I get the calculation `{{circle.percentage*(-140)/100 + 105 }}` by adjusting the dashoffset and guessing.

I have a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/10992/

As you can see, it only works for the circles from 30% to 70%. Does anyone know the correct calculation of it? I use the CSS tag as one of the tags of my question because the calculation should also work in CSS. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could have two circles that overlay each other. The first circle being the gray outline and the second circle being the progress overlay. Then change the `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` values of just the second circle and rotate the svg by 90 degrees:

html:

```
<circle cx="25" cy="25" r="22.5" stroke="rgb(188,188,188)" stroke-width="5" fill="none"></circle>
<circle cx="25" cy="25" r="22.5" stroke="rgb(0,51,117)" stroke-width="5" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="{{circle.circumference}}" stroke-dashoffset="{{circle.circumference * (1 - circle.percentage/100)}}"></circle>
```

js:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    var radius = 22.5;
    var circumference = Math.PI*(radius*2);
    $scope.circles = [];
    for(var i=0; i<=10; i++){
        var circle = {
            percentage : i* 10,
            circumference: circumference
      };
      $scope.circles.push(circle);
    }
}
```

css:

```
.progress {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

[Link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/10999/)

I found this [tutorial](https://codepen.io/xgad/post/svg-radial-progress-meters) helpful.

Comment: This works but still one `circle` overlaps the other. How to mark the "origin" of each one of the `circle`s?

Comment: The tutorial is really good, thanks you!

Answer (score 18):

The radius of your circle is 22.5, so the correct length for your dash array should be

```
(2 * PI * 22.5) = 141.37
```

Secondly, you can just use `stroke-dasharray` by itself. No need to use `stroke-dashoffset` also.

```
stroke-dasharray="{{circle.percentage*142/100}} 142"
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/10993/)

*Note: I removed the `stroke-linecap="square"`. You may want to put it back if you added that deliberately.*

Answer (score 0):

For any one who wonder, if you are making a ring pie-chart, the formula to calculate `stroke-dasharray` should be: `(width-thickness)` (assume thickness + innerCircleRadius + thickness = width = outerCircleRadius)